# access params in rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, ruby-grape

I am using grape and I would like to access the request params within the rescue_from:

```
class API < Grape::API

  rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
    rack_response({
  end
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to do with this:

```
rescue_from :all do |e|
  req = Rack::Request.new(env)
  ApiCallAudits.create data: {input_params: req.params.as_json}, backtrace: $!.to_s, status: :error
end
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try something like this:

```
rescue_from  Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
  env['api.endpoint'].helper_method
end
```

prams should be available in helper, but I'm not sure about this trick https://github.com/intridea/grape/issues/438

Answer (score 0):

a bit more recent answer in case anybody is still wondering about this:

```
rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
  env['grape.request'].params
end
```

see https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/pull/894

Answer (score 0):

`context.params` seems to be the way to do this in 2023 - from [the Grape Wiki on exception handling](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#exception-handling:%7E:text=Inside%20the%20rescue_from%20block%2C%20the%20environment%20of%20the%20original%20controller%20method(.self%20receiver)%20is%20accessible%20through%20the%20%23context%20method):

> Inside the rescue_from block, the environment of the original controller method(.self receiver) is accessible through the #context method.

e.g.

```
rescue_from :all do |e|
  user_id = context.params[:user_id]
  ...
end
```